# Losing track of OAuth2Swift for Instagram authentication

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, instagram, cocoapods

Working away, just about to ship, no real updates, [6.3.2] when out of the blue this error comes up.

Spent a day hacking away between OAuthSwift V0.3.4, 0.3.5, 0.3.6 and the same error happens. Also once (but super rare), I got a "can't find: OAuthSwift" type error. Wondering is it a  cocoapods thing or something basic I've got out of wack.

Pretty much absolutely nothing has changed in my OS/or development environment. At least that I know of.

Any help most appreciated. :-)

[image]

Comment: This screenshot is too small, can't see anything

Comment: Ok, went to 72dpi. Was on a Mac.

Comment: Ahh, you're right on retina is all clear. On my old 27" external monitor - not so well

Comment: Ok, i'm guessing at this point, somehow a path was lost to OAuthSwift. Everything is there, yet can't find those method calls. But just out of the blue, which is the funny part. I have installed Xcode7, but am not using it. Wondering it that has any connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be in this statement (fix):

```
oauthswift.authorizeWithCallbackURL( NSURL(string: "oauth-swift://oauth-callback/instagram")!, scope: "basic", state:state, success: {
  credential, response, parameters in
```

One version had the parameters version missing. Fixed.